# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection in r even after setting right path

Tags: r

loading required library

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")
```

vector for file names

```
files<- list.files(path = "C:/Users/91932/Downloads/archive (2)/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16",pattern =".csv")
```

concat directory to file names

```
files<-str_c("C:/Users/91932/Downloads/archive (2)/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16",files)
```

applying function to each element of vector

```
> map_df(.x = files, .f = read.csv,)
```

in above function map_df() i am getting  an error in file (file,"rt"), even after using setwd() to set path and checking using getwd() paths seems to be correct for .csv file .

why this error occurred? how to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the path is wrong: you forgot the trailing slash in the path prefix in `str_c`. However, rather than using `str_c`, you can instruct `list.files` to give you full paths from the get-go:

```
files <- list.files(
    path = "C:/Users/91932/Downloads/archive (2)/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16",
    pattern = ".csv",
    full.names = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! @konradrudolph that was of great help.